# Fade out on click isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on the "open" button,it fade out but "navigazione" div doesn't fade in. But If I try to put display: block; on the "navigazione ID" I can see the script working. Obviously I need that the "navigazione id" start with display none. where's the problem?? thank you in advance for your help!

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#close-icon").on('click', function() {
    $("#menu-butt").fadeIn();
    $("#navigazione").fadeOut();
});

$("#menu-butt").on('click', function() {
    $("#menu-butt").fadeOut();
    $("#navigazione").fadeIn();
});
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <div id="navigazione"> <div> <div id="button"> ciao </div> </div> 
  <div class="row menu-butt"><a href="#" id="menu-butt">open<a></div>
  <div id="close-icon"><a href="#" id="close-icon">close<a></div>
```

CSS

```
#navigazione { height: 100vh;
width:100%;
position: fixed  ;
top: 0px;
left: 0px; 
background-color: rgba(28,82,23,0.95);
z-index:400; 
display: none;
}

#close-icon{ position: fixed;
height: cover;
top: 20px; 
right: 30px !important;
z-index: 450 ;
display: none;

}
```

Comment: in your html  id:"navigazione"  should be id = "navigazione"

Comment: You start by using valid HTML...

Comment: Sorry for the mistake by the way it's not the problem, the code is right on dreamweaver.

Comment: You've also got elements with non-unique IDs and class names that match ID names...you should clean those up and your issue might become obvious to you.

Comment: @vlk I updated answer again please check!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you are looking for -

```js
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
      $("#close-icon").on('click', function() {
        $("#menu-butt").fadeIn();
        $("#navigazione").fadeOut();
    });
    
    $("#menu-butt").on('click', function() {
        $("#menu-butt").fadeOut();
        $("#navigazione").fadeIn();
    });
    });
```

```css
  #navigazione { height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed  ;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px; 
    background-color: rgba(28,82,23,0.95);
    z-index:400; 
    display: none;
    }
    
    #close-icon{ position: fixed;
    height: cover;
    top: 20px; 
    right: 30px !important;
    z-index: 450 ;
    
    }
    
    close-icon {
    color:#000;  
    }
    .menu-butt {
    color:#000;  
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigazione"> <div id="button"> ciao </div> </div>
<div class="row menu-butt"><a href="#" id="menu-butt">open</a></div>
<div id="close-icon"><a href="#" id="close-icon">close</a></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've not well understand what you have change

Comment: @vlk your code was fine only thing I change is color and display:none, also HTML there was some extra <div> element in your code.

Comment: Hi #Yogesh Sharma,
Thank you very much for your help, but that solution can't work fine for me because I've simplified the code here's putting text, in my original code's link's buttons are images and the background is a complex image, by the way I've solved the problem putting the tag style="display: none;" in the html instead to put it in the css, I don't know why I need to do this but seem impossible to fade in elements that has been set with display: none; in the css in this page, it's really strange. Maybe it could be cause by some row of bootstrap default css.